# Laravel - How to use command line artisan commands like migrate on hosted server

Tags: php, laravel, server, host, laravel-artisan

So when I use localhost I am using the cmd to run artisan commands. However when I upload my app on a server how can I run those kinds of commands? I searched but eventually got confused and I don't know what to do. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you run into any problem?

Comment: You have to ssh in to your server with a tools like http://www.putty.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this code, to run artisan commands form route or controller

```
//Setup route example
Route::get('/myapp/install/{key?}',  array('as' => 'install', function($key = null)
{
    if($key == "appSetup_key"){
    try {
      echo '<br>init migrate:install...';
      Artisan::call('migrate:install');
      echo 'done migrate:install';

      echo '<br>init with Sentry tables migrations...';
      Artisan::call('migrate', [
        '--package'=>'cartalyst/sentry'
        ]);
      echo 'done with Sentry';
      echo '<br>init with app tables migrations...';
      Artisan::call('migrate', [
        '--path'     => "app/database/migrations"
        ]);
      echo '<br>done with app tables migrations';
      echo '<br>init with Sentry tables seader...';
      Artisan::call('db:seed');
      echo '<br>done with Sentry tables seader';
    } catch (Exception $e) {
      Response::make($e->getMessage(), 500);
    }
  }else{
    App::abort(404);
  }
}
}));
```

From here : http://laravel-tricks.com/tricks/run-artisan-commands-form-route-or-controller

If you have full server access you can simply ssh you server run all commands, here are some links to ssh server

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-ssh-to-connect-to-a-remote-server-in-ubuntu

https://mediatemple.net/community/products/dv/204404604/using-ssh-in-putty-

Answer (score 0):

Some host do not allow php access so Artisan::call cause error. in such of this servers only way is `cron jobs` :
https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/scheduling